# I need help with this install error on VMWare player?

Tags: vmware-player

```
Failed to run '/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig' --icon='vmware-player' --appname='VMware' --gcc='/usr/bin/gcc' --headers='/lib/modules/4.13.0-45-generic/build/include' as user root
```

[image: VMWare Install Bug]

Answer (score 0):

sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all